Getting warnings when running a development build in expo
Hi I recently upgraded expo from expo SDK 50 to expo SDK 51 following the Expo native upgrade helper. However I keep getting some warnings when producing a development build. These are the warnings I am receiving
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:763:63: warning: Direct call to eval(), but lexical scope is not supported.
...typeof expo === "undefined" ? eval("require") : function (moduleId) {
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:3432:16: warning: the variable "SharedArrayBuffer" was not declared in function "from"
    if (typeof SharedArrayBuffer !== 'undefined' && (isInstance(value, Shared...
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:7430:18: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"
          typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' &&
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:19678:7: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "logCapturedError"
      setTimeout(function () {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:17788:31: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in anonymous function " 372#"
  var _nativeFabricUIManage = nativeFabricUIManager,
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:17816:21: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 372#"
    cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:22446:30: warning: the variable "__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__" was not declared in anonymous function " 372#"
  if ("undefined" !== typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:23995:5: warning: the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"
    setImmediate(function () {
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28033:5: warning: the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 583#"
    fetch,
    ^~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28034:5: warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 583#"
    Headers,
    ^~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28035:5: warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 583#"
    Request,
    ^~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28036:5: warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 583#"
    Response
    ^~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28193:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"
      var reader = new FileReader();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28244:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 594#"
        } else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                                   ^~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28246:40: warning: the variable "FormData" was not declared in anonymous function " 594#"
        } else if (support.formData && FormData.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                                       ^~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28248:44: warning: the variable "URLSearchParams" was not declared in anonymous function " 594#"
...e if (support.searchParams && URLSearchParams.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body...
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28367:26: warning: the variable "AbortController" was not declared in anonymous function " 600#"
          var ctrl = new AbortController();
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28501:23: warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 604#"
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:28046:71: warning: the variable "self" was not declared in anonymous function " 586#"
...undefined' && globalThis || typeof self !== 'undefined' && self ||
                                      ^~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:32070:27: warning: the variable "performance" was not declared in anonymous function " 761#"
  if ("object" === typeof performance && "function" === typeof performance.no...
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:32093:26: warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in anonymous function " 761#"
  "undefined" !== typeof navigator && undefined !== navigator.scheduling && u...
                         ^~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:32203:37: warning: the variable "MessageChannel" was not declared in anonymous function " 761#"
  };else if ("undefined" !== typeof MessageChannel) {
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:32218:34: warning: the variable "nativeRuntimeScheduler" was not declared in anonymous function " 761#"
... = "undefined" !== typeof nativeRuntimeScheduler ? nativeRuntimeScheduler....
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:43997:34: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "start 9#"
...    this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:79593:11: warning: the variable "cancelAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "cleanup"
          cancelAnimationFrame(this.splashScreenAnimationFrame);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:86829:20: warning: the variable "localStorage" was not declared in function "ColorSchemeStore"
        if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:86832:13: warning: the variable "document" was not declared in function "ColorSchemeStore"
            document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
            ^~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:130230:113: warning: the variable "Intl" was not declared in function "PluralResolver"
...ons.compatibilityJSON)) && (typeof Intl === 'undefined' || !Intl.PluralRul...
                                      ^~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:137581:25: warning: the variable "Atomics" was not declared in anonymous function " 4643#"
    '%Atomics%': typeof Atomics === 'undefined' ? undefined : Atomics,
                        ^~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:137598:38: warning: the variable "FinalizationRegistry" was not declared in anonymous function " 4643#"
...lizationRegistry%': typeof FinalizationRegistry === 'undefined' ? undefine...
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:137637:25: warning: the variable "WeakRef" was not declared in anonymous function " 4643#"
    '%WeakRef%': typeof WeakRef === 'undefined' ? undefined : WeakRef,
                        ^~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:140134:13: warning: the variable "Buffer" was not declared in function "isArrayBufferView"
    return !Buffer.isBuffer(b) && ArrayBuffer.isView(b);
            ^~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:143629:17: warning: the variable "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE" was not declared in function "validateAbortSignal"
      throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'AbortSignal', signal);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:143775:9: warning: the variable "queueMicrotask" was not declared in function "addAbortListener"
        queueMicrotask(function () {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:144204:17: warning: the variable "fn" was not declared in function "?anon_0_ 52#"
          yield fn(value, options);
                ^~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:180609:31: warning: the variable "normalizeDigits" was not declared in function "checkNumberGroupingIsValid"
    var normalizedCandidate = normalizeDigits(candidate, true
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:180616:28: warning: the variable "MetadataManager" was not declared in function "checkNumberGroupingIsValid"
    var alternateFormats = MetadataManager.getAlternateFormatsForCountry(numb...
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:180617:37: warning: the variable "util" was not declared in function "checkNumberGroupingIsValid"
    var nationalSignificantNumber = util.getNationalSignificantNumber(number);
                                    ^~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:180651:25: warning: the variable "formatNumber" was not declared in function "getNationalNumberGroups"
    var rfc3966Format = formatNumber(number, 'RFC3966', metadata); // We remo...
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:180664:53: warning: the variable "NON_DIGITS_PATTERN" was not declared in function "allNumberGroupsAreExactlyPresent"
...= normalizedCandidate.split(NON_DIGITS_PATTERN); // Set this to the last g...
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:180690:43: warning: the variable "CountryCodeSource" was not declared in function "allNumberGroupsRemainGrouped"
...r.getCountryCodeSource() !== CountryCodeSource.FROM_DEFAULT_COUNTRY) {
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:180712:65: warning: the variable "Character" was not declared in function "allNumberGroupsRemainGrouped"
...rRegion(region, true) != null && Character.isDigit(normalizedCandidate.cha...
                                    ^~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:187776:15: warning: the variable "toString" was not declared in anonymous function " 5853#"
    toString: toString,
              ^~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:192167:32: warning: the variable "crypto" was not declared in function "rng"
      getRandomValues = typeof crypto !== 'undefined' && crypto.getRandomValu...
                               ^~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:192167:130: warning: the variable "msCrypto" was not declared in function "rng"
...domValues.bind(crypto) || typeof msCrypto !== 'undefined' && typeof msCryp...
                                    ^~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:207025:14: warning: the variable "setInterval" was not declared in function "setInterval 1#"
      return setInterval.apply(undefined, __spreadArray([handler, timeout], _...
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:207029:101: warning: the variable "clearInterval" was not declared in function "clearInterval 1#"
...d : delegate.clearInterval) || clearInterval)(handle);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:241833:100: warning: the variable "location" was not declared in function "registerSensor 1#"
...(0, _PlatformChecker.isWeb)() && location.protocol !== 'https:' ? ' Make s...
                                    ^~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:243669:26: warning: Direct call to eval(), but lexical scope is not supported.
            workletFun = eval('(' + initData.code + '\n)');
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:243692:112: warning: the variable "_toString" was not declared in function "valueUnpacker"
...recognized by value unpacker: "${_toString(objectToUnpack)}".`);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:244785:33: warning: the variable "_WORKLET" was not declared in function "runOnJS"
      if (SHOULD_BE_USE_WEB || !_WORKLET) {
                                ^~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:262838:26: warning: the variable "structuredClone" was not declared in function "createAnimationWithExistingTransform"
      newAnimationData = structuredClone(_config.AnimationsData[animationName]);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:263158:24: warning: the variable "MutationObserver" was not declared in function "addHTMLMutationObserver"
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationsList) {
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:263207:41: warning: the variable "getComputedStyle" was not declared in function "fixElementPosition"
...entBorderTopValue = parseInt(getComputedStyle(parent).borderTopWidth);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:267798:5: warning: the variable "jest" was not declared in function "beforeTest"
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    ^~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:268413:26: warning: the variable "_getAnimationTimestamp" was not declared in function "computeEasingProgress"
      var elapsedTime = (_getAnimationTimestamp() - startingTimestamp) / 1000;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:305430:17: warning: the variable "TextDecoder" was not declared in anonymous function " 11486#"
            if (TextDecoder === undefined) {
                ^~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:338436:51: warning: the variable "FileList" was not declared in function "d 3#"
... instanceof Blob || e instanceof FileList) || !r && !n(e)) return e;
                                    ^~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:360590:26: warning: the variable "CustomEvent" was not declared in function "extractEventHiddenProperties"
    if (event instanceof CustomEvent) {
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:360669:16: warning: the variable "Event" was not declared in function "convertUnconventionalData"
    if (typeof Event !== "undefined" && data instanceof Event) {
               ^~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:360864:18: warning: Direct call to eval(), but lexical scope is not supported.
          return eval(`(${sourceSanitized})`);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/android/app/build/generated/assets/createBundleProductionDebugJsAndAssets/index.android.bundle:360867:19: warning: Direct call to eval(), but lexical scope is not supported.
          var f = eval(`(${sourceSanitized})`);

These are the versions upgraded to
"@expo/config-plugins": "8.0.0",
"@expo/metro-config": "0.18.11",
"@expo/metro-runtime": "3.2.3",
"expo": "51.0.35",
"expo-constants": "16.0.2",
"expo-document-picker": "12.0.2",
"expo-image-picker": "15.0.7",
"expo-linear-gradient": "13.0.2",
"expo-linking": "6.3.1",
"expo-media-library": "16.0.5",
"expo-router": "3.5.23",
"expo-secure-store": "13.0.2",
"expo-splash-screen": "0.27.6",
"expo-status-bar": "1.12.1",
"react-native": "0.74.5",

Any clarification why these warnings are popping out and how to get rid of these would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance
